# Python: why does `random.randint(a, b)` return a range inclusive of `b`?

Tags: python, random, integer, boundary

It has always seemed strange to me that `random.randint(a, b)` would return an integer in the range `[a, b]`, instead of `[a, b-1]` like `range(...)`.

Is there any reason for this apparent inconsistency?

Comment: (Not answering the question:) Well, you could use `randrange`.

Comment: Maybe I'm just not as savvy as you, but I don't see it as an inconsistency. I see it as just providing a method for for programmers to call an inclusively random number without needing to use operators and magic numbers. The better languages give their users avenues through which they can be creative.

Comment: @Musixauce3000 it's an inconsistency because both methods – `range` and `randint` – accept the same logical value (ie, a range of numbers), but that value is specified in two different – inconsistent – ways (ie, one is inclusive of the endpoint, the other is exclusive).

Comment: Why would you want it to be *less* intuitive?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

I tried to get to the bottom of this by examining some old sources.  I *suspected* that `randint` was implemented before Python's long integer: meaning that if you wanted a random number that included `INT_MAX`, you would have needed to call `random.randrange(0, INT_MAX + 1)` which would have overflowed and resulted in arguments of `(0, 0)` or `(0, INT_MIN)` depending.

However, looking as far back as even [the Python 1.5.2 sources](http://www.python.org/download/releases/1.5/), in `Lib/whrandom.py` we see:

```
#
# Get a random integer in the range [a, b] including both end points.
# (Deprecated; use randrange below.)
#
def randint(self, a, b):
    return self.randrange(a, b+1)
```

`whrandom.randint` was continued to be deprecated in [2.0](http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/release20-maint/Lib/whrandom.py?view=markup), [2.1](http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/release21-maint/Lib/whrandom.py?view=markup), [2.2](http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/release22-maint/Lib/whrandom.py?view=markup), and [2.3](http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/release23-maint/Lib/whrandom.py?view=markup); but `random.randint` was marked as deprecated in [2.1](http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/release21-maint/Lib/random.py?view=markup), although no longer marked as deprecated in [2.2](http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/release22-maint/Lib/random.py?view=markup).

Also, [`random.py` from version 2.1](http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/release21-maint/Lib/random.py?view=markup) is the first to note in `random.randint`'s docstring:

```
def randrange(self, start, stop=None, step=1, int=int, default=None):
    """Choose a random item from range(start, stop[, step]).

    This fixes the problem with randint() which includes the
    endpoint; in Python this is usually not what you want.
    Do not supply the 'int' and 'default' arguments.
    """
```

The only available source older than that is [the 0.9.1 source](http://www.python.org/download/releases/early/), and as far as I can tell, `randint` was not implemented at that point.

Thus, I conclude that the reasoning for `randint` *including* the endpoint is known to only Guido himself at this point; given the docstring from Python 2.1, it sounds like the reason may have been a simple mistake.

Comment: +1 for making the effort to research this, with some interesting observations.

Comment: Maybe the randint specification came from another language?

Answer (score 16):

I guess `random.randint` was just the first attempt at implementing this feature. It seems that the Python developers also felt that this was a problem, which is why in v1.5.2 they added another method [randrange](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.randrange) with more standard parameters:

> ```
> random.randrange([start], stop[, step])
> ```
>
> Return a randomly selected element from range(start, stop, step). This is equivalent to choice(range(start,  stop, step)), but doesn’t actually build a range object.

You can use `randrange` instead of `randint` to avoid surprising people.

On the other hand, in many situations where the problem is phrased as 'choose a random number between 1 and 6' it might be more natural to use `randint(1, 6)` instead of writing `randrange(1, 7)` or `randrange(min, max + 1)`.

Answer (score 10):

This is speculation, but normal human usage of 'give me a random number from a to b' is inclusive.  Implementing it that way sort of makes sense, given Python's general philosophy of being a more human-readable language.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's a reason for that. But at least it's documented.

Comment: +1: And the reason doesn't matter.  Even if it's not documented, it still doesn't matter.