# What is the difference between random.randint and randrange?

Tags: python

The only differences between `randrange` and `randint` that I know of are that with `randrange([start], stop[, step])` you can pass a `step` argument and `random.randrange(0, 1)` will not consider the last item, while `randint(0, 1)` returns a choice inclusive of the last item.

So, I don't understand why `randrange(0, 1)` doesn't return `0` or `1`. Why would I use `randrange(0, 2)` instead of a `randrange(0, 1)` which does?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568783/python-why-does-random-randinta-b-return-a-range-inclusive-of-b/2568917#2568917

Comment: You have two values you want to return and 2-0=2 (2 not included in range). count of range(a,b) is always b-a and often clearest way to write the range is range(a,a+count)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The [docs on `randrange`](https://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.randrange) say:

> `random.randrange([start], stop[, step])`
>
> Return a randomly selected element from `range(start, stop, step)`. **This is equivalent to `choice(range(start, stop, step))`**, but doesn’t actually build a range object.

And `range(start, stop)` returns `[start, start+step, ..., stop-1]`, not `[start, start+step, ..., stop]`. As for why... zero-based counting rules and `range(n)` should return `n` elements, I suppose. Most useful for getting a random index, I suppose.

While [`randint` is documented as](https://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.randint):

> `random.randint(a, b)`
>
> Return a random integer N such that `a <= N <= b`. **Alias for `randrange(a, b+1)`**

So `randint` is for when you have the maximum and minimum value for the random number you want.

Comment: rng = np.random.default_rng()
rng.integers()

Answer (score 60):

[https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/.../Lib/random.py#L218](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a445feb72902e4a3c5ae712f0c289309e1580d52/Lib/random.py#L218)

```
    def randint(self, a, b):
        """Return random integer in range [a, b], including both end points.
        """

        return self.randrange(a, b+1)
```

Answer (score 5):

A **range** in python is something that includes the lower-bound but *does not include the upper-bound*. At first, this may seem confusing but it is intentional and it is used throughout python.

```
list(range(4, 10))
#     [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
#     does not include 10!

xs = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']  
xs[1:4]  
#     [xs[1], xs[2], xs[3]] 
#     does not include xs[4]!

bisect.bisect_left('jack', names, 2, 5)
#     perform a binary search on names[2], names[3], names[4]
#     does not include names[5]!

random.randrange(4, 8)
#     picks a random number from 4, 5, 6, 7
#     does not include 8!
```

In mathematics, this is called a [**half-open interval**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-open_interval). Python chooses to use half-intervals because they avoid [**off-by-one errors**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error):

> [to avoid off-by-one errors] ... ranges in computing are often represented by **half-open intervals**; the range from m to n (inclusive) is represented by the range from m (inclusive) to n + 1 (exclusive)

And so as a result, most python library functions will use this idea 
of half-open ranges when possible.

However **randint** is one that *does not* use half-open intervals.

```
random.randint(4, 8)
#     picks a random number from 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
#     it does indeed include 8!
```

The reason is historical:

- **randint** was added early in [v1.5](https://docs.python.org/release/1.5/lib/node79.html#SECTION006300000000000000000) circa 1998 and this function name was used for generating both random floating-point numbers randomly and [integers](https://docs.python.org/release/1.5/lib/node80.html#SECTION006400000000000000000) randomly
- **randrange** was added in python in v1.5.2. In [v2.0](https://docs.python.org/release/2.0/lib/rng-objects.html), a notice was added saying that randint is *deprecated*.
- the deprecation notice for randint has since been removed

randint started off as an earlier library function that didn't include half-open interval because this idea was less cemented in python at the time.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between the two of them is that `randint` can only be used when you know both interval limits.
If you only know the first limit of the interval `randint` will return an  error. In this case you can use `randrange` with only one interval and it will work.
Try run the following code for filling the screen with random triangles:

```
import random
from tkinter import *

tk = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack()

def random_triangle(l1,l2,l3,l4,l5,l6):
  x1 = random.randrange(l1)
  y1 = random.randrange(l2)
  x2 = x1 + random.randrange(l3)
  y2 = y1 + random.randrange(l4)
  x3 = x2 + random.randrange(l5)
  y3 = y2 + random.randrange(l6)
  canvas.create_polygon(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3)

for x in range(0, 100):
  random_triangle(300,400,200,500,400,100)
```

Try running again the above code with the `randint` function. You will see that you will get an error message.

Answer (score 0):

Actually... `randint()` uses `randrange()` to generate random integers.

```
>>> randint(1.0,2.1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    randint(1.0,2.1)
  File "C:\Users\Anonymous\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\random.py", line 222, in randint
    return self.randrange(a, b+1) <----- LOOK HERE
  File "C:\Users\Anonymous\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\random.py", line 195, in randrange
    raise ValueError("non-integer stop for randrange()")
ValueError: non-integer stop for randrange()
```