# List index out of range error with Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
for x in range (0,24):
  RandCharGen = random.randint(0,len(characters)) 
  RandChar = characters[RandCharGen]
```

Shows the error:

```
RandChar = characters[RandCharGen]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Does anyone have the solution?

Comment: Quick remark: name your variables by PEP8 standard like snake_case: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case.

Comment: `randint` returns numbers *including* the second value, which results in an out-of-bounds access.

Comment: you need `randrange` then

Comment: `len(characters) -1`?

Answer (score 1):

as explained in comments, you can get out of bounds for your string, unless you use `random.randrange`, which was added to avoid this issue (which can be stealthy because of the random aspect). More about this: [Difference between random randint vs randrange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540431/difference-between-random-randint-vs-randrange)

But a better solution would be `random.choice` to pick a random item from your string/list:

```
for x in range (0,24):
  RandChar = random.choice(characters)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `randint` function returns a value including *both* end points. If `characters` was 10 characters long, the highest number it could return is 10, which would be higher than the highest index, 9. You can change it to this:

```
for x in range (0,24):
    RandCharGen = random.randint(0,len(characters)-1) 
    RandChar = characters[RandCharGen]
```

or this:

```
for x in range (0,24):
    RandChar = random.choice(characters)
```