# Python - List index out of range, "for" loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I don't get how a "for" loop that iterates through the elements of a list can be out of range.
First part seems to be okay as I can print it.

```
import random

def random_list(n):
    l = []
    for i in range(0,n):
        l.append(random.randint(0,n))

    return l


def maximum(n):
    x = 0
    b = random_list(n)
    for i in b:
        if b[i] > x:
            x = b[i]


print (maximum(10))
```

Comment: Please include the error message. Python showed you the line with the error, seems kinda rude not to share!

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
for i in b:
    if b[i] > x:
        x = b[i]
```

Iterates over the elements of `b`, not the indices. Change it to

```
for i in b:
    if i > x:
        x = i
```

You also need to return something from your function, probably `x`.

Comment: I may have worded poorly, the idea is to fetch the maximum number in a list, therefore i thought I needed the elements in b not the index.

Comment: Though if I DO edit the code like that, it just return None

Comment: @PeterPefi Yes, but `for i in b` iterates over the elements. Compare that to `for index in range(len(b)):`. Also, you need to return something from your function (probably `x`).

Comment: so i would contain the value of the element while in the for-loop and not the counting index?

Comment: Oof yeah it was just the return I forgot, thank you kindly.

Comment: Yes. This is easy to test with `for i in b: print(i)`.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you know how to iterate over a list in python, the error could be due to `randint`, which generates an integer in the interval [low, high]. This means `high` is a possible output, while the highest index in your program is `high - 1`.

For example,

```
random.randint(0, 0)
```

gives `0`.

Similarly, `random.randint(10)` can return `10`.

If you don't understand how to iterate over a list in Python, consider a simple example:

Take the list below:

```
myList = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Now, there are two ways to iterate over the list:

1. Directly accessing elements:

   ```
   for element in myList:
       print(element, end=" ")
   ```

This gives the output:

```
1 3 5 7 9
```

2. Accessing elements using indices

   ```
   for idx in range(len(myList)):
       print(idx, ":", myList[idx], end=" ")
   ```

This gives the output:

```
0:1 1:3 2:5 3:7 4:9
```

Comment: I fear this might have flown over my head. Wouldn't the range function limit the range to 0,n(exclusive) so basically n-1, which should be fine?

Comment: The randomly generated numbers aren't an issue in this case. Also, for the second scenario in this answer, it would definitely be better to use `enumerate`.

Comment: `randint` includes `n` as a possible generated number; its range is 0(inclusive) to n(inclusive). [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568783/python-why-does-random-randinta-b-return-a-range-inclusive-of-b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568783/python-why-does-random-randinta-b-return-a-range-inclusive-of-b)